# @Html.TextBoxFor throws System.FormatException when the localized string contains curly brace character

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string

`@Html.TextBoxFor` throws `System.FormatException` when the localized string contains curly brace character

```
public class MyModel
{
  [Display(ResourceType = typeof(MyModelResourceProvider), Name="MyProperty")]
  public string MyProperty { get; set; } 
  ...
}

public class MyModelResourceProvider
{
  public static string MyProperty
  {
    return GetLocalizedString("stringresourcekey");
  }
}
```

`GetLocalizedString` gets the localized string using the `stringresourcekey`. The localized string could contain characters such as curly brace, hash, apostrophe etc.

My cshtml uses the MyProperty as follows.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyProperty, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

When I run my asp.net mvc application in Visual Studio the above line throws `System.FormatException`. I know this is happening due to the curly brace character. But where and how do I escape it? If I try to escape by replacing the curly brace with double curly braces in `GetLocalizedString` the Html renders double curly braces instead of single.

**Update 1**

What I want is that since I am escaping the curly brace with double curly braces in `GetLocalizedString` method (i.e. in C#) I want to display single curly brace instead of double curly braces in HTML.

Comment: You probably need to [HTMLEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) the string before consuming it in the view

Comment: @Liam I tried using WebUtility.HtmlEncode(GetLocalizedString("stringresourcekey")), but I am getting the same  error. Am I doing it at the right place?

Comment: Have you tried replace curly brace with double curly brace?

Comment: @GeneR Yes, if I replace curly brace with double curly braces the exception is not thrown, but the Html then renders double curly braces instead of single curly brace.

Comment: Use a backslash to escape the curly brace?

Answer (score 0):

Include the `HtmlEncode()` in your view like

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Server.HtmlEncode(model.MyProperty))
```